# Installing haskell platform fails

Tags: installation, opensuse, make, haskell

I am trying to install `haskell-platform-2011.2.0.1` onto my SUSE 11.4. I have got all the dependencies required for `./configure`, which works ok. But when getting to `make`, it builds with this error:

> `scripts/build.sh`
>
> Scanning system for any installed Haskell Platform components...
>
> Found: None.
>
> New packages to install: None! All done.
>
> Building transformers-0.2.2.0 "/usr/bin/ghc" "--make" "Setup" "-o"
>   "Setup" "-package" "Cabal" Linking Setup ... "./Setup" "configure"
>   "--package-db=../../packages/package.conf.inplace"
>   "--prefix=/usr/local" "--with-compiler=/usr/bin/ghc"
>   "--with-hc-pkg=/usr/bin/ghc-pkg" "--with-hsc2hs=/usr/bin/hsc2hs"
>   "--enable-library-profiling"
>   "--ghc-pkg-option=--package-conf=../../packages/package.conf.inplace"
>   Configuring transformers-0.2.2.0... "./Setup" "build" Preprocessing
>   library transformers-0.2.2.0... Building transformers-0.2.2.0...
>
> Control/Monad/IO/Class.hs:19:7: Could not find module System.IO':
>   Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for
>   packagebase'? Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
>
> Error: Building the transformers-0.2.2.0 package failed make: *
>   [build.stamp] Error 2

How do I install the missing `System.IO` module?